# Choppy image using Oculus VR camerarig

Tags: camera, oculus, virtual-reality

I am experimenting with this person's code for making portals, you can see the video of the portal working here-- http://algoholic.eu/unity3d-4-indie-free-portal-effect-with-no-stencil-and-no-render-to-texture/

My project works fine when I don't use my rift but when I drop the CameraRig in and configure it, I get this effect and I dont know what it is:
Start game: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHjh1.jpg
Move in any direction: http://imgur.com/K6iXgcO

The portal image is choppy. Is this ...clipping? Is it not drawing fast enough for both eye anchors? Like I said, I dont know what it is so I don't know where to start for fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a limitation of the algorithm. I downloaded it get the above if I move an object close to the portal window. (try and position the green cube within 1m of the portal window).